# Can't get PHP password_hash api to work

Tags: php, security, hash

So I hashed the string "test"

```
$hash = password_hash("test", PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Saved it in my password field (varchar 255)

Then I made a simple test login page

```
if (!empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
{

$username = trim($_POST['username']);
$password = trim($_POST['password']);

$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT username, password FROM users WHERE username = ? AND password = ?");
$stmt->execute(array($username, $password));
$row = $stmt->fetch();
$hash = $row['password'];

if (password_verify($password, $hash)) {
//success
} else {
 //wrong credentials
}
```

Then I enter my username and password `test`, but it return false when it should return true (but obviously im wrong since it dont, im missing something here)

What am I doing wrong here?

Been reading alot about it but i cant figure out why it wont return true. Please note that im a novice.

Also why is the salt, I guess, the first 6 characters, that begins in the hash always the same? `$2y$10`. That cant be good.

Comment: Your literal input `$password` won't match in the SELECT query, when that column contains a hash.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My guess is that you are storing the hashed password in the database.

In the where clause you need to pass it the hashed password, not the plain text

`$stmt->execute(array($username, password_hash($password)));`

Same thing in the if statement, make sure both are hashed

Comment: I just realized this....god im stupid

Comment: @Smugglaren no you're not, happens to the best of us!

Comment: That's the wrong approach. You'll get a differently salted hash with each `password_hash()` call. It will never match the database content.

Comment: @mario I'm not native to php so I don't know the function exactly, but at least he understands the root of the problem

Comment: yeah this is not correct but i got it working now